# Can any primitive type be passed into a function expecting a pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Basically I'm wondering what the rules are for passing in pointers vs references to functions in C++. I couldn't find them stated anywhere. Can you pass a primitive type integer, for example, into a function expecting a pointer? Can't you *only* pass in pointers to methods expecting pointers?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing the code corresponding to the cases you are interested in, and compiling with full warnings/running to test?

Comment: Please do not post text in images. Copy-paste or (re-)type the text directly into the question instead. See [ask].

Comment: Where in your example do you think a non-pointer is passed to a function expecting a pointer? I don't see any.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your question and the code supplied. If you have a specific question about what the code does, please state it. (BTW, the indicated answer of `3` is wrong)

Comment: Your image (which, as @walnut mentioned, shouldn't be here) has nothing to do with the question.
BTW the answer is 2.

Comment: But `increment2` won't work. because the body should be `++*x;`

Comment: @lakeweb Incrementing the pointer one-past-the-object is allowed.

Comment: @walnut Yes, but it does nothing and looks goofy in context. I guess that is the point here. Thanks.

Comment: Only `increment2` expects a pointer. And the code passes one in.

Comment: @lakeweb Yes, both `increment1` and `increment2` are obviously *wrong* in the sense that they are never useful for anything, but as you said, this seems to me to be the point of the exercise.

Comment: Fairly certain this question actually wants to ask *What is the difference between a pointer and a reference function parameter*, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/315052) is close, but not quite a dup.

Comment: When in doubt, try running it. If the output doesn't make sense, try debugging it and look closely at what's going on. If that still doesn't make sense, then that's a good time to ask about the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is just a memory address and in c++ you can get the address of a variable by using the `&`. Here is an example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void increment(int& x)
{
    ++x;
}

void increment2(int* x)
{
    ++(*x);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int * p = new int(1);

    increment2(&i);
    increment2(p);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;

    increment(i);
    increment(*p);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
2
2
3
3
```

try it: 
https://godbolt.org/z/br9APq